# use vendor address instead of store main address for shipping and taxes calculation

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using WooCommerce and WCFM Marketplace on my site to allow "others" (registered vendors) to sell goods on my site, I am using UPS for shipping (their official plugin, everything is setup and connected), I noticed that when calculating shipping costs (and maybe taxes too) UPS is using main store address (in woocommerce settings) and not Vendor store address (entered in WCFM marketplace) from where vendor will ship goods, is there any way to make UPS use vendor address instead of Main store address?
I searched for this in google but didn't find any straight answer on my question.

Comment: At first glance it uses the address on the UPS account number. Do your vendors have their own UPS accounts or are you shipping everything from your own account? I don't see any easy way to override the address per account number for an individual shipment, no. The relevant code is in ups-eu-woo-model-ups-shipping-api.php I think.

Comment: But I think your best bet is to ask on [the plugin's support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/ups-eu-woocommerce/), not here. Or if you find one of the replies there that UPS has written there's an email address to contact them directly.

Comment: I need that on cart page calculation of shipping cost was considering address of seller not store address, I use UPS shipping from my account because buyer pays site all the fees and I pay for shipping (sending shiping label to seller), but need somehow tell woocommerce to calculate shipping according to seller address.

Comment: Right, then you'll need to modify the UPS plugin I think. Look in src/models/ups-eu-woo-model-ups-shipping-api.php for $data_params->shipfrom. There's no filter you can hook alas I don't think - you'll need to fork and edit the plugin.

Comment: is there any way to modify woocommerce default behavior "to use address entered in settings for shipping and taxes calculation"?

Comment: I don't know, sorry, but even if there was you'd need to modify the UPS plugin because I think that's just set up to use the address on the account number as the ship-from address.

Comment: It probably is worth contacting UPS through the plugin support forum anyway in case they can help, e.g. they may be willing to modify the plugin to implement this or make it easier for people to do this in the future at least. But I don't think there's a setting you can change to make this work without code changes.

Comment: Ok, I will try to modify file you mentioned, can you give me some direction how to find needed variable for vendor store address, it will appreciated. thanks

Comment: I don't know sorry. I assume that comes from WCFM which I don't know either.

Comment: I can't find any way to contact them (there is no answer on plugin support page), I can't call directly because I am not in USA.

Comment: Thank you for your replies :)

Comment: There's an email address in this reply: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/does-not-work-by-states-or-zip-codes/

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!  I Couldn't find any email until now.